# Module's __getattr__ is called twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

[PEP-562](https://peps.python.org/pep-0562/) introduced `__getattr__` for modules. While testing I noticed this magic method is called twice when called in this form: `from X import Y`.

**file_b.py**:

```py
def __getattr__(name):
    print("__getattr__ called:", name)
```

**file_a.py**:

```py
from file_b import foo, bar
```

**output**:

```
__getattr__ called: __path__
__getattr__ called: foo
__getattr__ called: bar
__getattr__ called: foo
__getattr__ called: bar
```

I run it with: `python file_a.py`. The interpreter version is: 3.10.6

Could you please let me know the reason behind this?

Comment: The import machinery is sure complex. We will have to take a dive into its workings to check why this is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your `__getattr__` returns `None` for `__path__` instead of raising an `AttributeError`, the import machinery thinks your `file_b` is a package. `None` isn't actually a valid `__path__`, but all `__import__` [checks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.6/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L1148) here is `hasattr(module, '__path__')`. It doesn't check the value:

```
elif hasattr(module, '__path__'):
    return _handle_fromlist(module, fromlist, _gcd_import)
```

Because the import machinery thinks your `file_b` is a package, it calls [`_handle_fromlist`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.6/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L1053), the function responsible for loading package submodules specified in a `from` import. `_handle_fromlist` will go through all the names you specified, and for each one, it will call `hasattr` to check whether an attribute with that name exists on `file_b`. If an attribute is not found, `_handle_fromlist` will attempt to import a submodule with the given name:

```
for x in fromlist:
    if not isinstance(x, str):
        if recursive:
            where = module.__name__ + '.__all__'
        else:
            where = "``from list''"
        raise TypeError(f"Item in {where} must be str, "
                        f"not {type(x).__name__}")
    elif x == '*':
        if not recursive and hasattr(module, '__all__'):
            _handle_fromlist(module, module.__all__, import_,
                             recursive=True)
    elif not hasattr(module, x):
        from_name = '{}.{}'.format(module.__name__, x)
        try:
            _call_with_frames_removed(import_, from_name)
        except ModuleNotFoundError as exc:
            # Backwards-compatibility dictates we ignore failed
            # imports triggered by fromlist for modules that don't
            # exist.
            if (exc.name == from_name and
                sys.modules.get(from_name, _NEEDS_LOADING) is not None):
                continue
            raise
```

This is where the first `__getattr__` calls come from: `hasattr` attempts to get the `foo` and `bar` attributes on `file_b`, triggering your `__getattr__`.

The second `__getattr__` calls are just the calls you would expect, retrieving the `foo` and `bar` attributes you said to import so the `import` statement can assign them to names in the namespace the `import` was executed in.